# Please change the color of the hats/usernames on the Winter Bash 2020 /stats page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020

On the [Winter Bash stats page](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/stats), the color of the hat names and the users they were awarded to is not really a great color:

[image]

It requires a bit more effort to read than, for instance, the [stats from WB 2019](https://contests.stackoverflow.com/promos/20/winter-bash-2019):

[image]

The blue color `#06abf9b3` provides a much better contrast:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Not that it has to be that color specifically, but just something a bit easier to read please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Link colors have been fixed. Hopefully more readable now.

> bad contrast with links
> colored backgrounds annoying
> more readable now?

Comment: It's indeed very readable now but seems like everything is bold, which contradicts the note on top _Secret hats are bold._ There is no difference between normal and secret hats now.

Comment: related: at the blog this link Enough stats for today! If you want more, there’s a ton of stats on the **public stats page** goes to `/leaderboard` and not to `/stats`

Comment: if you remove `font-weight: bold;` from the a element fixes that problem@Adina has pointed out

Comment: Secret hats are now bold, non-secret are normal

Answer (score 7):

To stay coherent with the UI themes, the light blue is a bit out of context. I'd use

```
a {
    color: #8a2857;
}
```

which makes a great contrast and matches the colors of the main UI design:

[image]

Comment: Hmm, yeah.  Looks pretty nice.  More opinions, please y'all!

Comment: Is that supposed to be “top spot” instead of “top stop” ?